# why wont the image blit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have tried putting the fill color before blit but it won't work.
im using python 3.8.2, windows 10, and pygame 1.9.6.
please help
btw im following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w) tutorial (im new to pygame)
and here's my code

```
import pygame

#initialize
pygame.init()

#screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#things
pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders 1.0")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#player settings
playerimg = pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')
playerx = 370
playery = 430

#define player
def player():
   screen.blit(playerimg, (playerx, playery))

#loop
running = True
while running:

   #rgb
   screen.fill((10, 0, 0))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
         running = False

   player()
   pygame.display.update()

#end process
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

ill answer any questions
(side note it crashes when I press "x" and exits when I press '-' idk why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is not a function - it's a constant, simply an integer representing a `QUIT` event. You can't do `if event.type == pygame.QUIT()`, you need to do `if event.type == pygame.QUIT`, without parenthesis.

You also don't really need to call `pygame.quit()` and `exit()` at the end of the program - both pygame and the program itself will be terminated when the program reaches its end.

Apart from that your program works for me, images are showing. Make sure your image is visible over a black background and if it is and you are still having problems I'll try to help you with them.

Comment: that you for answering my noob question, I'm 4 years late to respond, hope you are doing well!